# animate popup to scroll from bottom to top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, modal-dialog, popup

I want to animate my popup modal to scroll from bottom to top, right now I have it at faded in. I tried replacing that with animate scroll top but wasn't working and not sure if i'm implementing it correctly. Please help, thank you and much appreciate it. My code are below.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    console.log('scrolling - '+$("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed'));
    if (!$("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed')) {
        $(".popup-close").click(function(e){
            closeSPopup(e);
        });

        var a = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (a > 400) {
            $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeIn();
        }
    }
});

function closeSPopup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed',true);
    $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to animate with this library [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: Great. I will try that. Thank you.